# Custom Post Type and Taxonomy combination

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Is it possible to create a permalink/template structure like this:

```
www.example.com/attractions                  <-- post type archive
www.example.com/attractions/museums          <-- taxonomy archive
www.example.com/attractions/van-gogh-museum  <-- custom post type
```

After trying for days I can only get 1 of the 2 combinations to work: either *post type + post type archive* or *taxonomy + taxonomy archive*

Not sure what to do next: am I overlooking something, do I need a plugin, should I set this up differently?

**=== edit ===**

(just thinking out loud)

At the moment I´m using post type and taxonomy rewrite capabilities, like this:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'attractions'),
```

but maybe I should go another route and manually set "attractions" as the parent page of both the custom post type and the taxonomy archive.

**===/edit===**

I hope some one can point me in the right direction. All suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I´ve asked this question on the WP Support forums as well, will update this thread when I receive an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add the new post_type and taxonomy
add_action('init', function(){
    // Add a post_type named 'testype'
    register_post_type($postype = 'testype', $arguments = array(
        'name'                  => $postype,
        'label'                 => 'Test',
        'public'                => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'supports'              => array(
            'title', 'excerpt', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'comments',
        ),
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => array(
            'with_front'    => false,
            'pages'         => true,
            'feeds'         => true,
            'slug'          => 'test/read',
            // This is my custom work, not stock functionality
            // 'permastruct'    => '%id%'
        ),
        'query_var'             => 'testing',
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        '_builtin'              => false,
    ));
    register_taxonomy($postax = 'testax', $postype, array(
        'label'         => 'Tax',
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'rewrite'       => array(
            'with_front'        => false,
            'pages'             => true,
            'feeds'             => true,
            'slug'              => 'test/browse',
        ),
        'public'            => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_tagcloud'     => false,
    ));
});
// Add the 'snippet' postype to the loop.
add_action('pre_get_posts', function(\WP_Query $query){
    if(!is_archive()) return; // Only for archives!
    // If suppress_filters is on, bail here :) (no idea what this really does)
    if(!empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])) return;
    // Add a new post type to the loop if we are visiting the archive
    // of a taxonomy assigned to the post.
    if(!empty($query->query_vars['testax'])){
        $post_types = $query->get('post_type');
        if(empty($post_types)) $post_types = array('post');
        elseif(is_string($post_types)) $post_types = array($post_types);
        // Add the new post_type now
        $query->set('post_type', array_merge($post_types, array('testype')));
    }
    return;
});
```

**Cheers!** This is fully functional and commented. It has PHP 5.3 syntax as I don't do 5.2 anymore and I'm also sort of lazy. I'm sure you can handle the function extraction if you still use 5.2.

*Let me know how it goes, and if you have questions.*

Comment: Wow thanks so much for your help :) I´m running PHP 5.3 - I´ll test it tonight!

Comment: @Mattvic Make sure you refresh the Permalinks by visiting the Settings - Permalinks page and saving settings. IMPORTANT!

Comment: During the week I´ve tried your code, but unfortunately I couldn´t it to work. Basically, I can´t have the post type and the taxonomy archive on the same level, like this: 

`example.com/attractions/ (<- post archive)`
`example.com/attractions/history-museum (<- custom post)`
`example.com/attractions/museums/ (<- taxonomy archive)`

I think that my question was a bit confusing as well. I´ll post a new, more specific question. 

Thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**See if this answer helps:**
[How to add a link(href) so when i click it, it renders (shows all) posts of custom post type (rich_media), from the current category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32137/how-to-add-a-linkhref-so-when-i-click-it-it-renders-shows-all-posts-of-cust/32138#32138)

You need to add the new **post_type** to the **pre_get_posts** to have stuff work properly in **Term Archives** *(Categories, Tags)*. And make sure you enable **archive** on your custom post type.

Comment: Thanks, but I don´t think that´s the solution. 

I ´m probably trying to do something wrong, rewriting both the post type archive and the taxonomy archive to the same URL...